# pushstate - back button not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, browser-history, pushstate

If I use ajax to change specific portions of the page, like a content section, which warrants a new URL (and requires one specifically for favoriting, or refreshing), is there some magic that I am not aware of that allows the user to click the back button and reload the content that was just there?

Or do you have to re-retrieve the data based on stored variables using popstate

Thanks!

Comment: you have to re-retrieve the data based on stored variables using popstate